# Finding matrix eigenvectors using QR decomposition

Tags: matrix-decomposition, svd, linear-algebra

**First**, a general linear algebra question: Can a matrix have more than one set of (unit size) eigenvectors? From a different angle: Is it possible that different decomposition methods/algorithms (QR, NIPALS, SVD, Householder etc.) give different sets of eigenvectors for the *same* matrix?

**Second**, regarding QR decomposition: Are the columns of the Q matrix the eigenvectors? How can their eigenvalues be easily found (post the QR decomposition)?

Comment: **First**: Yes. Can you think of an example? (*Hint*: Try to find an example where *every* orthogonal matrix is a set of eigenvectors). **Second** (partial): Eigenvectors are only guaranteed to be orthogonal when the underlying matrix is symmetric. If you think about that, that answers a lot of your question right away. For diagonalizable matrices an eigendecomposition takes the form $X = P D P^{-1}$.

Comment: Is this the right place for this question (asking sincerely, not rhetorically)? Certainly linear algebra is important in statistics, but I don't see any statistical content here per se.

Comment: Also, I will defer to @cardinal in terms of how much help is appropriate to give here, but I think it would be helpful to explain/link to the correct way to find eigenvalues via QR decomposition, which IMO is not at all obvious and would be hard to discover even with good hints.

Comment: I believe this question might be of interest for people using multivariate statistics where matrix decomposition are extensively used, although it focus on linear algebra and not statistics *per se* (which probably explains the 2 votes to close). Do you have a possible statistical  application in mind?

Comment: I answered in the comments in [this question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20554/pcas-principle-and-available-algorithms)... doesn’t it qualify as a duplicate?

Comment: Thanks for all. Sorry, question should have probably been asked on the Mathematics StackExchange, although I've asked it in a context of a statistics-related task...

Comment: @Elvis, I think some elaboration on your comment in the other question would make a fine answer to this one. Probably no need to go into shifts and other ways of speeding up the algorithm you allude to, though the basic one has somewhat poor convergence properties.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The (basic) algorithm with QR decomposition is as follows.

- Let $X$ by a symmetric matrix.
- Let $X_1 = X$, and iterate the following:
- Given $X_k$, write a QR decomposition $X_k = Q_k R_k$, and let $X_{k+1} = R_k Q_k$;
- The matrices sequence $X_n$ converges to some diagonal matrix $D$ with the eigenvalues on the diagonal; you retrieve the corresponding eigenvectors as the columns of $\prod_i Q_i$.

Here is an example code in R.

```
# some symmetric matrix
A <- matrix( sample(1:30,16), ncol=4)
A <- A + t(A);

# initialize
X <- A;
pQ <- diag(1, dim(A)[1]);

# iterate 
for(i in 1:30)
{
  d <- qr(X);
  Q <- qr.Q(d);
  pQ <- pQ %*% Q;
  X <- qr.R(d) %*% Q;
}
```

Now we have a look on the result

```
> A
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   52   30   49   28
[2,]   30   50    8   44
[3,]   49    8   46   16
[4,]   28   44   16   22
```

The matrix X contains the eigenvalues on the diagonal:

```
> round(X,5)
         [,1]    [,2]      [,3]     [,4]
[1,] 132.6279  0.0000   0.00000  0.00000
[2,]   0.0000 52.4423   0.00000  0.00000
[3,]   0.0000  0.0000 -11.54113  0.00000
[4,]   0.0000  0.0000   0.00000 -3.52904
```

And the product of all Q contains the eigenvectors:

```
> round(pQ,5)
        [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]
[1,] 0.60946 -0.29992 -0.09988 -0.72707
[2,] 0.48785  0.65200  0.57725  0.06069
[3,] 0.46658 -0.60196  0.22156  0.60898
[4,] 0.41577  0.35013 -0.77956  0.31117
```

We can compare to the result of `eigen(A)` :

```
> eigen(A)
$values
[1] 132.627875  52.442300  -3.529045 -11.541131

$vectors
           [,1]       [,2]        [,3]        [,4]
[1,] -0.6094595 -0.2999194  0.72707077  0.09987744
[2,] -0.4878528  0.6519967 -0.06068999 -0.57724915
[3,] -0.4665778 -0.6019623 -0.60897966 -0.22156327
[4,] -0.4157690  0.3501285 -0.31117293  0.77956246
```

Of there is room for lots of improvements, but basically here it is. I once read lots of papers on the subject but my memory is leacking :(

Note that, as your problem is to perform PCA, you will find easily many PCA programs on the internet, you may prefer to do than rather than program it yourself.

Comment: Thanks much. I've implemented it, but it seems it takes a long time for this algorithm to converge. Could you please also briefly explain the SVD algorithm (similarly to the above)? I read about it, but did not find an explanation as simple and to-the-point as yours.

Comment: @YanRaf 1) What convergence criterion do you use? You shouldn’t wait until non-diagonal coefficients are null, but stop for example as soon as they are < 0.001 in absolute value... this should be precise enough. 2), the SVD. This is much more complicated, there is a part to construct a tridiagonal matrix that I don’t remember at all. The brute force version is to compute the product $A \times A'$ or $A' \times A$ to have the smallest possible square symmetric matrix, and to compute its PC that are the singular vectors of A.

Comment: Thanks. 1) I'm using this exact convergence criterion, i.e. non-diagonal coefficients (absolute values) should be epsilon distant from 0, at most.

Comment: Hi, I think I spotted an error in your code. I tried it and this is the results I got : https://gist.github.com/gbersac/4335bc17ca38fe07f7b3   The eigen vectors are ok, but the eigen values are wrong. Could you fix that please.

Comment: The error is in your code. Try with `A <- Origin` instead.

Comment: It works great only in the given example with low number of iterations to get correct eigenvectors. When u start using floating point type matrix the error is huge for all vectors except first column

Comment: Why symmetric? Shouldn't QR decomposition work for any square matrix (and in a generalized sense even for non-square matrices as well)?

Comment: @mikuszefski do you have the answer of that question?

Comment: @AlexandroPalacios I can only guess that the choice of "symmetric" ensures real eigenvalues here.I know that the [python implementation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.qr.html) has no such restriction

Answer (score 6):

Sorry it's a bit late, but I think there is still room for basic answers.

> First, a general linear algebra question: Can a matrix have more than
>   one set of (unit size) eigenvectors?

If the eigenvalues are distinct, the answer is "No". If there are duplicate eigenvalues, then for these eigenvalues, the eigenvectors are not distinct (but any eigenvectors corresponding to unique eigenvalues are still distinct).

For example, if you are looking at a matrix with iid Gaussian entries, then barring some floating point fluke, it will not have repeat eigenvalues, and hence the eigenvectors will be uniquely determined.

> Second, regarding QR decomposition: Are the columns of the Q matrix
>   the eigenvectors? How can their eigenvalues be easily found (post the
>   QR decomposition)?

The QR does not give this to you, but the rank-revealing QR (RRQR) does, and there are known bounds on the error. You should not implement either the QR or the RRQR yourself since there is excellent code and this is a major topic of research in numerical linear algebra. (The big issues: stability and taking advantage of memory and communication to make it efficient)

For a reference on the RRQR giving bounds on the eigenvalues, try [Some applications of the rank revealing QR factorization](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0913043) (1992), by T F Chan and P C Hansen.

Also, be careful with the distinction of the **QR Factorization** and the **QR Algorithm**. The QR Algorithm, which the other answer shows, uses QR factorizations at every step, hence the name, but otherwise they are different algorithms. You asked about the QR Factorization/Decomposition, and got an answer with the QR Algorithm.

On wikipedia, check out "QR_algorithm" compared to "QR_decomposition"

Comment: Re the first answer: you should be more explicit about what you mean by two sets of eigenvectors to be the "same". After all, the $1$ by $1$ matrix $(1)$ has distinct eigenvalues $\{1\}$ for which the unit vectors $(1)$ and $(-1)$ are both eigenvectors, but few people would consider the sets $\{(1)\}$ and $\{(-1)\}$ to be the same.

Comment: True. Any non-zero multiple of an eigenvector is still an eigenvector (and even with the SVD, there is still a +/- issue). So what I mean by "distinct" is that two vectors are distinct if they are linearly independent.

Basically, every eigenvalue corresponds to an eigenspace, and the dimension of that eigenspace matches the multiplicity of the eigenvalue. So if the multiplicity is larger than 1, then there are infinitely many non-trivial choices of a basis (i.e. eigenvectors) for that space.